# fail to use an android device like a bluetooth gps

Tags: gps, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, nmea, bluez, raspbian

I would like to use my android phone (ICS 4.0.1) like a bluetooth GPS with my rasperry pi.  My current destribution is raspbian. 
I tried several application from the Google Play, but finaly I Chose blueNmea.  It creates a RFCOM/L2CAP channel to broadcast the GPS position on the bluetooth stream.

When I browse the available bluetooth services on the raspberry, I see the blueNmea RFCOM/L2CAP channel.  But when I try to use the channel, the error "Invalid exchange" occurs

I tried two ways to use the service, with the rfcomm command and with the pybluez wrapper.  The same error occurs with the two ways.

I think that blueNmea doesn't see the rasperrry and so doesn't send the nmea data.  The blueNmea app has a "connected client" list and the raspberry never appears on this list.

I also tried to pair the two device together but there is no difference.

It's also possible to use blueNmea on a TCP/IP connection, I tested with my notebook and it works fine.

thanks.